# ArrayController set('model'...) vs set('content'...)

Tags: ember.js

In the guide documentation for ArrayController, content is set on the controller via the Route like so:

```
controller.set('model', playlist.get('songs'));
```

However, in the API docs, it is being set like so:

```
MyApp.listController.set('content', data);
```

Keying on the `model` vs `content`... The code from the guide, setting the 'model' does not work.  I had to go by the API docs to set the content so my items would show up in my list.

Is the Guide example wrong?  Or is it appropriate for a situation that I am just not familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's partially wrong. `model` is used for `ObjectController`s and `content` is used for `(Array)Controller`s.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from Ember.js source code `model` is just an alias for `content` inside of each `controller`

```
model: Ember.computed.alias('content')
```

Comment: That may be the case, but it doesn't work if I use model.  It only works if I use content.  So I don't believe it is just that simple.

Comment: This is only true for `ObjectController`s

Comment: It does seem that this is true for every controller - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/controller.js#L44

Comment: @Myslik no, it's not. check the source for ArrayController, it's overridden.